# Como saber cuando se cierra una ventana con python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como puedo saber cuando se cierra una aplicación? Mi idea es que este siempre abierta por lo que cuando se cierre la quiero volver a abrir. Esto se puede hacer con Python? 
Seria de ayuda que me dijeran como. Gracias
Estoy usando python 3

Comment: Hola Roberto, faltan muchos detalles para poder concretar algo ¿una aplicación creada con Python o externa? Si es con Python ¿que framework?¿Por qué se cierra (el usuario la cierra, apagado del sistema, excepción interna, etc)?¿Si es un proceso externo lo lanza Python como subproceso o no?¿Qué sistema operativo?¿Debe estar siempre abierta aunque se reinicie el sistema?¿Iniciar automáticamente al arranque o cuando el usuario la ejecute?, etc Deberías intentar concretar más la situación concreta y lo esperado. Un saludo.

Comment: Vaya no pense tanto... Tienes razon. No, simplemente es un .exe de windows. La aplicacion da error y al dar ese error se cierra. Lo que yo quiero es que cuando esta se cierre, un script de python la abra. Alguna duda mas? Gracias de antemano

Comment: @FJSevilla tienes idea de como solucionarlo ahora?